# WebP Images Google Safari Image Optimization

Tags: magento2, image, optimization, lazyload

WebP Images Google Safari Image Optimization

We are using Amasty Google Page Speed Optmization Extension for Magento 2 which has Image Optimization options - There are options to covert images to webp format - which is preferred by Google but I have read that webp format is not supported by safari apple browser devices -

So I am confused if I do convert all images to webp format does this mean they will not show in safari browser or they will show the normal image i.e. .jpg .png  .gif etc  in safari  and the webp images in google or other browser that support this image format

Comment: Ask Amasty if they handle fallback on JPG if WebP is not supported on the visitor browser. Quick remember for compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Comment: thanks will check do you know any extension which have fallback to jpg plz

Comment: Never used it but they say it does the job: https://marketplace.magento.com/jajuma-module-webpimages.html

Comment: Nice spot that looks the business will try and update

Comment: I checked with amasty and they confirmed that it already has the fallback option for safari browsers its called User Agent so will test it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebP has such a nuance - not all browsers support it. For example, iOS Safari, regular Safari, IE - do not support WebP. https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp Therefore, you must always store at least two versions of each image. Webp (for WebP-enabled browsers) and original image. And give the right version depending on the browser. And the original image must also be optimized/compressed - so that even for browsers without WebP support, images will be optimized (lighter in weight) - this is the third! version of the file.. At the optipic service, I recently noticed a new functionality in which all of this is already in the box. https://optipic.io/en/cdn/ You can even connect everything so that the urls of the images do not change (they remain exactly the same and look like internal urls on my site). But in fact, they are loaded through their system with automatic compression, conversion to webp and recognition of webp support. It turns out that everything is simple and beautiful, and inexpensive))